# ListBoxItem selection on TextBox focus

Tags: wpf, textbox, listbox, selection

I have a ListBox showing items using the following DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate" DataType="{x:Type DAL:ResultItem}" >
  <StackPanel Width="280" >
    <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding FullName1, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    ... 
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am using a transparent, read-only, borderless TextBox as opposed to a TextBlock because I want users to be able to select the text for copying. Should I do it differently?
How can I write this so that when the user clicks on the TextBox, the ListBoxItem gets selected as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found that the answer is just to do this from the ListBoxItem standpoint, adding the following to its DataTemplate:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Once I figured out to put that in the ItemContainerStyle of the listbox it's all good to go!

Comment: For full XAML, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960098/set-listboxitem-isselected-when-child-textbox-is-focused/2962961#2962961