# How make WPF Listbox child datatemplate controls select the ListBoxItem container when clicked?

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox, listboxitem, childcontrol

I have a listbox and in the datatemplate I have an Expander.

If I click on the Expander Header, the expander expand the content zone but not make the parent ListBoxItem Selected.

If I click on the Expanded Content Zone of the Expander, the parent ListBoxItem become selected.

How to make that when clicking the expanderHeader, the content become expanded AND the parent listboxitem become selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and handled it by listening to the PreviewGotKeyboardFocus event on the ListBox.  When the focus changes walk the visual tree looking for a ListBoxItem and select it:

```
    private void ListBox_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus( object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( e.NewFocus is FrameworkElement )
        {
            ListBoxItem item = ( e.NewFocus as FrameworkElement ).FindParent<ListBoxItem>();
            if( item != null && !item.IsSelected )
            {
                item.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static T FindParent<T>( this FrameworkElement element ) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        DependencyObject current = element;

        while( current != null )
        {
            if( current is T )
            {
                return ( T ) current;
            }

            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( current );
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I realise that this question has been answered, but there is a much simpler way to achieve this desired result. You can add a `Trigger` to the `ListBoxItem Style` that will select the `ListBoxItem` whenever an element in its `ItemTemplate` has keyboard focus:

```
<Style.Triggers> 
  <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"> 
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/> 
  </Trigger> 
</Style.Triggers>
```

For more information, view [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin.aspx), or [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913144/wpf-listboxitem-selection) or [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960098/set-listboxitem-isselected-when-child-textbox-is-focused/2962961#2962961).

Comment: I really like this solution. No code behind, purely WPF. Very clean @Sheridan

Answer (score 0):

can't you use the `Expanded` event for that ?

something like

```
<Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded"
```

and

```
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    parentListBox.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something you can do is to bind the IsExpanded Property of the Expander directly with the IsSelected Property of the ListBoxItem.
But this means, that is you just select an item the expander gets expanded too...
And it means too that unselected items are never expanded.

example:

```
  <ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}">
          <TextBlock Text="bla bla" />
        </Expander>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Items>
      <DataObject />
      <DataObject />
    </ListBox.Items>
  </ListBox>
```

Comment: yes, and this is not a good thing. i have to emulate somthing like a tree-view/list-view with custom controls (like progressbars etc) ... so i need all groups can be expanded or collapsed...