# WP8 Select ListBoxItem when contained TextBox gets focus

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, focus, selecteditem

On Windows Phone 8 I have a listbox and the DataTemplate for each ListboxItem contains Textboxes (and also checkboxes etc.)

Now when a user clicks on the TextBox (Checkbox etc) it gets the focus, but the SelectedItem property of the Listbox doesn't change. I need to know which Item in the list the user is currently editing and I use the MVVM pattern, so I bind on SelectedItem.

For WPF I found several approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913144/listboxitem-selection-on-textbox-focus), but none of them works on WP8, mostly because there are no Triggers on WP8.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Get the actual TextBox when it is Focused as the SelectedItem?

Answer (score 0):

Use GotFocus event of TextBox to get ListBoxItem.

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem itemSelected = sender as ListBoxItem;
    listBox.SelectedItem = itemSelected;
    // You can also get underlying data context of MVVM by
    // MyDataContextClass selected = itemSelected.DataContext as MyDataContextClass;
    // where MyDataContextClass is the class with which you are binding ListBoxItem
}
```